# Retrieve & dump type information from IDA Pro

Tags: ida, c++, idapython, dumping, script

I want to retrieve IDA Pro .idb database's each type info, such as:

- *size and name of a structure;*
- *each member variable type and name;*
- *each member variable size and offset;*

And dump it to a .h file in a formatted manner. ("Create C header file..." just dumps without sizes and offsets and does not allow to pre-format it.) How to do this?

Comment: You can use [ida_struct](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_struct.html) API to retrieve the needed information via Python terminal/plugins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's obviously doable (you already noted the `Create C header file` functionality), but if you want to customize the output, you'll have to code it yourself.

Here's what you'll need:

- `ida_typeinf.first_named_type` and `ida_typeinf.next_named_type` to iterate through all of the type names in a TIL (i.e., the main TIL for an IDB).
- To retrieve a `tinfo_t` type object from a type name, create `tif = ida_typeinf.tinfo_t()`, then do `tif.get_named_type(name)` with the name returned from the functions above.
- Once you have the `tinfo_t tif` object, if `tif.is_struct()` returns `True`, you can get the structure details via the function `tif.get_udt_details` by passing it a new `ida_typeinf.udt_type_data_t` data structure.
- `ida_typeinf.udt_type_data_t` is a vector of `udt_member_t` objects (plus additional information, e.g. size and alignment). Each `udt_member_t` object describes one field in a `struct` or `union`. You can retrieve member names via the `.name` field, and each field's `tinfo_t` type via the `.type` field.

That's all you need. However, if you've never worked with types programmatically before, you're going to find it tricky. It is already evident from the above that `tinfo_t` is a mutually recursive data structure, i.e., the `tinfo_t` for a structure contains other data structures (like `udt_type_data_t`) that themselves contain `tinfo_t` objects to describe structure field types. Due to the mutual recursion in the data structures, functions involving `tinfo_t` objects are often mutually recursive.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer! I will try this

Comment: Very nice. Thanks for the explanation. It took me like 2 hours to find your answer and only then I managed to understand how I have to walk up the inheritance tree all the classes and also walk all the members of classes.